# ClassNotFoundException anonfun when deploy scala code to Spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt, classnotfoundexception

I'm new to Apache Spark and I'm trying to deploy a piece of simple scala code to the Spark.

**Note:** I am trying to connect to a an existing running cluster which I configure via my java parameters to be: `spark.master=spark://MyHostName:7077`

Environment

- **Spark** 1.5.1 build with scala 2.10
- Spark runs **standalone** mode on my local machine
- **OS**: Mac OS El Captain
- **JVM**: JDK 1.8.0_60
- **IDE**: IntelliJ IDEA Community 14.1.5
- **Scala** version: 2.10.4

**sbt**: 0.13.8

**Code**

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object HelloSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/README.md"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    println("%s done!".format(numAs))
  }
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "data-streamer210"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-bagel_2.10" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "1.5.1"
)
```

**Error**

```
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at HelloSpark.scala:14
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at HelloSpark.scala:14) with 2 output partitions
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(count at HelloSpark.scala:14)
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at HelloSpark.scala:14), which has no missing parents
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3192) called with curMem=120313, maxMem=2061647216
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 1966.0 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1892) called with curMem=123505, maxMem=2061647216
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1892.0 B, free 1966.0 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:50941 (size: 1892.0 B, free: 1966.1 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at HelloSpark.scala:14)
15/10/19 19:40:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@127.0.0.1:50951/user/Executor#-147774947]) with ID 0
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@127.0.0.1:50952/user/Executor#1450479604]) with ID 2
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@127.0.0.1:50957/user/Executor#1447408721]) with ID 1
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@127.0.0.1:50955/user/Executor#1397136754]) with ID 3
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.1:50963 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 127.0.0.1, 50963)
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.1:50964 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, 127.0.0.1, 50964)
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.1:50965 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 127.0.0.1, 50965)
15/10/19 19:40:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.1:50966 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(3, 127.0.0.1, 50966)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:50963 (size: 1892.0 B, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 127.0.0.1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloSpark$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 1]
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:50966 (size: 1892.0 B, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 127.0.0.1:50964 (size: 1892.0 B, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 2]
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 3]
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 4]
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 5]
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 127.0.0.1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2160 bytes)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor 127.0.0.1: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (HelloSpark$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 6]
15/10/19 19:40:11 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at HelloSpark.scala:14) failed in 2.613 s
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at HelloSpark.scala:14, took 2.716305 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 127.0.0.1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloSpark$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
    at HelloSpark$.main(HelloSpark.scala:14)
    at HelloSpark.main(HelloSpark.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloSpark$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/10/19 19:40:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 127.0.0.1): org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://127.0.0.1:4040
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
15/10/19 19:40:11 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/q9/m_d81ms107n09tj8k5wbzfb40000gp/T/spark-53ce9474-5488-4d50-bfb6-c58ddeed7640

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Also tried with Scala 2.11.7. Same error.

Comment: chcck the content of your jar!

Comment: How do you run this? Are you using spark-submit? If yes, can you show the command you use?

Comment: @marios I run this inside the IntelliJ IDEA by clicking the Run button. Without the anonymous function everything is fine.

Comment: Did you try with `new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]")...then all your options`?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Please could you explain a bit more about the reason why it fails without setMaster("local[1]")?

Comment: Try to initialize your SparkConf without using the setMaster. Then print the `conf.toDebugString`. What do you see in the "spark.master" entry? I think for some reason your "spark.master" might be pointing to a cluster that doesn't have your code loaded.

Comment: @marios the toDebugString output is spark.master=spark://MyHostName:7077 because I added the spark master as a JVM parameter. i.e. spark.master=spark://MyHostName:7077, which is the same as shown on the localhost:8080 spark web UI. There are 4 workers configured locally by setting SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4

Comment: This is what I thought. I just update a complete answer to what is happening (to the best of my knowledge).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you run Spark from IntelliJ you can either connect to a "local" spark JVM or to a remote cluster.

If you set you master to be local (e.g., `setMaster("local[*]")`), then any code you have in your local scope/project will be available to this temporary, local (single JVM) cluster you just created. Everything runs locally and will exit when your tests ends (if you running a unit test), or when you exit the app if you are running it as an app inside IntelliJ.

However, if you set master to point to a remote cluster (say `setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")`) you need to make sure that your cluster has access to your new code (in your case it needs to have access to the closure you are passing to `filter`).

When I want to execute a new piece of code on a running Spark cluster, I usually do that by packaging my app in an Uber Jar (see [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)) and then passing this as an argument in [spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) (see more details by clicking on the link).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - much appreciated!

Comment: @marios : How do you send the jar if you don't want to use spark-submit? In my case, i want to programmatically submit the job and work on the result.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4924). You might also want to look at the job server project [here](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver).

Comment: I solved my issue in this way. Thank you very much. 
Could you please give me some more details about what "making sure that your cluster has access to your new code" means?

Comment: @HosangJeon, I am glad it helped. Spark naturally runs on multiple JVMs. Each JVM needs to have all the code so it can load the classes call the methods on them and so on. You need to have a way to deliver your code (your classes) to all the JVMs in the cluster. Spark submit is an easy way for you to do that.

Comment: To elaborate more on how adding to spark-submit helps, Spark starts a file server in its driver and serves the jars. Executor are aware of the file server ad downloads the jar and makes it available as part of Executor's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an interesting interaction if you call setMaster in your code, even if you have it set to the right master.  For example, I had code like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://greine:7077")
```

that I submitted like this:

```
bin/spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster /Users/james/Projects/sparkHelloWorld/target/scala-2.11/sparkHelloWorld-assembly-1.0.jar
```

The jar (*sparkHelloWorld-assembly-1.0.jar*) I believe was built correctly and had all the required class files.  It still got an error:

```
17/04/08 09:19:08 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 10.178.252.14, executor 1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleApp$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Once I removed the call to `setMaster("spark://greine:7077")` it ran and completed correctly, using the same spark-submit command.